# Prove that $\sqrt{ab+c}+\sqrt{bc+a}+\sqrt{ac+b} \ge 1+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Prove that $\sqrt{ab+c}+\sqrt{bc+a}+\sqrt{ac+b} \ge 1+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$

It is given that $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers

Then I reduced the inequality to

$\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}+\sqrt{(1-b)(1-c)}+\sqrt{(1-c)(1-a)} \ge 1+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$.

I know that

$\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)} \ge \sqrt{ab}$. Similarly we can deduce other too.By this we get

$\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}+\sqrt{(1-b)(1-c)}+\sqrt{(1-c)(1-a)} \ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$

I don't know how they got 1 on rhs.Any help??

Comment: You have $\sqrt{ab+c}\geq \sqrt{ab}+c$, and the likes.  This can be proved with AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, or simple expansion.  So, $$\sum \sqrt{ab+c}\geq \sum\sqrt{ab}+\sum c=\sum\sqrt{ab}+1.$$

Comment: I am not sure how you go about proving it using am gm

Comment: By AM-GM, $a+b\ge 2\sqrt ab$.  So $ab+c=ab+(a+b)c+c^2\ge ab+2\sqrt{ab}c+c^2$.

Comment: I think it does not prove your result.can you make it more clear??

Comment: How much clearer do you want?  I just proved that $$\sqrt{ab+c}^2=ab+c\ge ab+2\sqrt{ab}c+c^2=(\sqrt{ab}+c)^2.$$ How does it not prove my result?  I think, perhaps you should start with simpler exercises for AM-GM to better see how to use AM-GM.

Comment: I understood it now.thanks

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I arrived finally to the equation on my own which is essentially same  as your comments and added my answer. (Deleted my previous answer though) but I see that it has been already answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$a,b,c>0 \text{ s.t. }a+b+c=1 \implies \sqrt{ab+c}+\sqrt{bc+a}+\sqrt{ca+b} \ge 1+ \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54597/a-b-c0-text-s-t-abc-1-implies-sqrtabc-sqrtbca-sqrtcab-ge-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a(a+b+c)+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}((a+b)(a+c)+2(a+b)\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}((a+b)(a+c)+2(a+b)(\sqrt{ab}+c)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a^2+7ab+2\sqrt{a^3b}+2\sqrt{a^3c})}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(a+b+c)^2+\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt{a^3b}+2\sqrt{a^3c}+5ab)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$(a+b+c)^2+\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt{a^3b}+2\sqrt{a^3c}+5ab)\geq$$
$$\geq(a+b+c)^2+2(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}+\sum_{cyc}(ab+2a\sqrt{bc})$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4ab-4c\sqrt{ab})\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

The equality $(a+c)(b+c)\geq(\sqrt{ab}+c)^2$ we can prove also by AM-GM:
$$(a+c)(b+c)-(\sqrt{ab}+c)^2=ab+ac+bc+c^2-ab-2c\sqrt{ab}-c^2=$$
$$=ac+bc-2c\sqrt{bc}\geq2\sqrt{ac\cdot bc}-2c\sqrt{bc}=0,$$
which gives much more easier solution:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}\geq\sum_{cyc}(a+\sqrt{bc})=1+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}.$$

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you provide an answer using on am gm because this problem is meant to be solved by am gm and I am curious how it can be done

Comment: @Mathematical Curiosity I added something. See now.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM inequality $$\frac{(a+b)}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

$$ a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ ca+cb \ge 2c\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ ca+cb+c^2+ab \ge c^2+ab+ 2c\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ c(a+b+c)+ab \ge c^2+ab+ 2c\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ c+ab \ge \left(c+\sqrt{ab}\right)^2 $$
$$ \sqrt{c+ab} \ge c+\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ \implies \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{c+ab} \ge \sum_{cyc}c+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab} $$
$$ \implies \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab+c} \ge 1+\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab} $$
which is same as the given equation, hence proved

Comment: I hope I did not do any mistake this time..

Comment: Seems good to me